# Unable to run cap deploy:setup on ec2, the task `deploy:setup' does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have installed ruby (using rvm), phusion passenger, & all or requirements.

Also on ec2 I get success message when I run $ ssh -T git@github.com

But when i try to run -> $cap deploy:setup, I get an error message
the task `deploy:setup' does not exist

cap -vT

```
➜  bridge1 git:(master) cap -vT
cap bundle:install # Install the current Bundler environment.
cap deploy:restart # 
cap deploy:start   # 
cap deploy:stop    # 
cap invoke         # Invoke a single command on the remote servers.
cap shell          # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.

Extended help may be available for these tasks.
Type `cap -e taskname' to view it.
```

this is my deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
#using  RVM!
$:.unshift("#{ENV["HOME"]}/.rvm/lib")
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_type, :user


set :application, "capi_app"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

role :web, "184.169.135.60"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "184.169.135.60"                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "184.169.135.60", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run


default_run_options[:pty] =  true
set :repository,  "git@github.com:jaipratik/gibridge1.git"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"


set :user, "ubuntu"            
set :use_sudo, false
set :admin_runner, "ubuntu"

set :rails_env, 'production'     
#set :use_sudo, false   #if error delete this


# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
 gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'


group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end


group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

Comment: What is in your Capfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions on the specific folder wasn't right, chmod 700 helped.

Answer (score 14):

Go to your application directory and run:

```
capify .
```

Comment: New version of capistrano has different command. Please take a look https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v3.3.3/README.md

Answer (score 2):

This just happenned to me, I was mistakenly typing the command into the terminal window that was connected to the vps server and getting the same error: the task deploy:update does not exist.

You need to type the cap command into your local terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```

in your deploy.rb, the correct command would be

```
cap production deploy:setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Capify does work as user1524695 pointed out, but what it's really looking for is the line

```
load 'deploy'
```

which loads the built-in deploy tasks.  If you're running a standard Capistrano script in the standard locations (with config/deploy.rb and Capfile set up relative to your working directory), Capfile will load the config/deploy.rb it generated by default.  If you're running a script in an arbitrary location for some reason, just add that line to the top of your script, then

```
cap -f /path/to/myscript.rb deploy:setup
```

should work as expected, even if the directory is not Capified.